# Find single matching record from one table with exact list of matches in join table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, I will show simplified versions.  I am looking to find an exact match from the first table, where I have the exact list of entries in the second table (as multiple individual records in the join table will match the primary key of the first table).

```
Table Metrics:

MetricsId:  (primary key)
A: (some parameter)
B: (some parameter)
C: (some parameter)
```

Like this:

```
MetricsId    A    B    C
-------------------------- 
    1       0.5  0.2  3.5 
    2       0.1  0.1  4.5 
    3       1.1  1.0  3.0


TABLE Metrics_Grid:
MetricsId (foreign key to Metrics
GridId (foreign key to another table)

MetricsId   GridId
---------------------
   1           12
   1           13
   1           14
   1           15
   2           12
   3           13
```

The record in the metrics table represents the metrics generated for specific parameters and for a specific set of grids.  The second table is the table containing the list of grids, but having a record for each grid that is included for that metrics record.   A single grid can be in multiple lists (E.g. say you had metrics for a single grid, it would have an entry, and that metrics entry would have only one in the link table, then you may have metrics for a collection of grids including the single grid (there are actually metrics records for each individual, then a group, every time metrics are run)

What I need to do is find when an exact match of the parameters AND the list of grids are already in the database, and return that one match or nothing.  So I need to find a match like this:

to start , I have the list of the the exact gridIDs that need to match (this is coded in java, using Spring JdbcTemplate, so I can pass in the list in whatever form I need)

```
Select M.* from Metrics M
Where
A=? AND B=? AND C=?
AND 
EXISTS (SELECT MG.GridId From MetricsGrid MG where MG.MetricsId=M.MetricsId) 
** This is where I get lost **
AND <THE LIST OF THE THE GridsIds matches exactly the list I have>
```

I tried a few things that were wrong and I know why they were wrong, like this one: which just passed back any metrics record that had the grid_id, so I got multiples instead of just one.

So for example, I want to be able to ask for the Metrics record matching A=0.5, B=0.2, c=3.5 AND GridIds = (12, 13, 14, 15)
or similarly, he Metrics record matching the same parameters, but only GridId 12

My attempts at it always return all the records.  I tried using Group By.. Having Count(), but couldn't get that right.  I think this isn't hard and my brain is just stuck.

I haven't found something similar, but it seems like it would be a common thing?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.metricsid, m.a, m.b, m.c
FROM metrics as m
INNER JOIN metrics_grid as mg on m.metricsid = mg.metricsid
WHERE m.a = ?
AND m.b = ?
AND m.c = ?
AND mg.gridid IN (?, ?, ?)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT MG2.GridId FROM Metrics_grid MG2 WHERE M.MetricId=MG2.MetricsId AND MG2.SensorID NOT IN (?,?,?))
```

Make sure you have indexes on m.a, m.b, m.c, and mg.gridid

Comment: This does exactly what my other attempts do, it returns both metrics records, the one where it is alone in the list, and the one where it is in a list of multiple.  There needs to be a way to check that it matches exactly and only the same list of grids, and that's where I'm struggling.

Comment: So I was able to make it work by adding this: AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT MG2.GridId FROM Metrics_grid MG2 WHERE M.MetricId=MG2.MetricsId
    AND MG2.SensorID NOT IN (?,?,?))    This did the part where it excludes any that are not exact matches.

Comment: Oh, if you update your answer with this, I'll accept your answer!

Comment: @titania424 I added your additional portion to the query.

Comment: So after testing, I found I have to add something else that I haven't figured out.  The query still returns 2 records when searching for the group, it works when only searching to match the single one.  When I get that, I'll post it and you can add it in.

Comment: Here's what I came up with: 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT m.metricsid, m.a, m.b, m.c, COUNT(*) AS MATCH_COUNT
FROM metrics as m
INNER JOIN metrics_grid as mg on m.metricsid = mg.metricsid
WHERE m.a = ?
AND m.b = ?
AND m.c = ?
AND mg.gridid IN (?, ?, ?)
GROUP BY m.metricsid) TMP WHERE TMP.MATCH_COUNT=3;
So this selects from a result that groups it by the metrics id, and counts how many rows match, and that has to match the total number that there should be.   Just glad I got it working, it was causing real problems here with recomputing huge amounts of metrics that already existed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the result you need using below query. The steps are:

1. Search for `MetricsIds` that have exactly the same `GridIds` as you want. You can get this done by using `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY`, `WHERE` and `HAVING`.

   First select all `MetricsIds` which have a gridId from the list you have.

   Remove the duplicates with distinct command.

   Then do a group by and count the number of gridIds for each `MetricsId`.

   Let's say you are looking for 4 specific gridIds so you filter out other results by using the `HAVING` command.
2. Search for all `MetricsIds` that have the correct criteria for `A,B,C` from `Metrics` table.
3. Perform an `inner join` between results of previous steps

   ```
   SELECT m.MetricsId from Metrics AS m join
       (SELECT DISTINCT mg.MetricsId, COUNT(mg.GridId) AS cnt FROM Metrics_Grid AS mg
   WHERE GridId in (12,13,14,15)
   GROUP BY mg.MetricsId) AS k ON m.MetricsId = k.MetricsId
   WHERE m.A =0.5 AND m.B = 0.2 AND m.C=3.5;
   ```

Comment: thanks for thinking about it, Your way may also work, but I found another solution building on the previous one.